# calling rest api from meteor app

Tags: rest, meteor

How can I call a `rest api` with authentication from meteor, appreciate if you can guide to an example, I have added the http package to the meteor project. Using advanced rest client chrome app, I am able to get the data by passing the following URL and  2 headers. This app is using the already logged in browser session.

```
URL: https://xxxxx:9443/ccm/oslc/contexts/_ZoC0QNS3EeGPlow7Bl9IAw/workitems
headers:    Accept", "application/json"
                OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0"
```

How can I pass the headers and user name password of the rest api service.

Comment: i found on the jazz forum someone has achieved using the XHR, the following is the code link, how can i map it to meteor package methods.Any idea appreciated.
https://jazz.net/forum/questions/170030/rtc-oslc-authenticate-with-javascript?page=1&focusedAnswerId=215145#215145